# VBScript Unterminated String Constant

Tags: windows-8, vbscript

I took this script from a website. I am trying to add shortcuts to taskbar and start menu on windows 8. My VBScript knowledge is quite weak. I'm pretty sure I am just missing a " somewhere but I'm not exactly sure where. The first 'String' after the Else WScript.Echo is not showing up in blue in my text editor as it should be so there may be something there as well. Any help would be much appreciated. (The error is claiming to be on 5, 60)

```
'Pin an application to a start menu or task bar
If WScript.Arguments.Count = 3 then
Call PinApplicationToTaskBar(WScript.Arguments(0), WScript.Arguments(1), WScript.Arguments(2))
Else
WScript.Echo "Missing parameters. String AppPathAndName  _
String ShortcutName Boolean OnStartMenu." & vbCr & vbCr & "  _
Example cmd.exe CMD  false" & vbCr & vbCr & _
"  Example %windir%\system32\SnippingTool.exe SnipIt false" 
End If

Public Sub PinApplicationToTaskBar(AppPathAndName, ShortcutName, OnStartMenu)
'This is on for a soft failure. 
'Uncomment this if error checking for a hard failure is needed for debugging.
On Error Resume Next

Dim FileSystemObj, ObjShell, ObjShellApp
Set ObjShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set FileSystemObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Create a temp location for the short-cut to exist
TempShortcutLocation = FileSystemObj.GetFolder_
(ObjShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%TEMP%"))
'Where is it being pinned too?  Determine the location where the pinned item will reside.
If(trim(lcase(OnStartMenu)) = "true") then ' pinned to start menu
    HasItAlreadyBeenPinnedShortCut = ObjShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings_
    ("%APPDATA%") & _
    "\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\StartMenu"
Else
    HasItAlreadyBeenPinnedShortCut = ObjShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings_
    ("%APPDATA%") & _
    "\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar"
End If
'Temporary location for the application short-cut
TempShortcut = TempShortcutLocation & "\" & ShortcutName & ".lnk"
'Possible location of a pinned item
HasItAlreadyBeenPinnedShortCut =  HasItAlreadyBeenPinnedShortCut & "\" & ShortcutName & ".lnk"
'If this already exists, than exit this procedure. The application has already been pinned.
If(FileSystemObj.FileExists(HasItAlreadyBeenPinnedShortCut)) Then
    'MsgBox(HasItAlreadyBeenPinnedShortCut & " Already Pinned")
    Set ObjShell = Nothing
    Set FileSystemObj = Nothing
    Exit Sub
End If
'Create a short-cut using the shell
Set lnk = ObjShell.CreateShortcut(TempShortcut)
lnk.TargetPath = AppPathAndName ' Full application path and name
lnk.Arguments = ""
lnk.Description = ShortcutName 'The name that appears on the start menu.
lnk.Save 

Set ObjShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

'Get the newly created short-cut full path
Set ShortCutToPin =  ObjShellApp.NameSpace(TempShortcutLocation) 

If(FileSystemObj.FileExists(TempShortcut)) Then 
    Dim ShortCutToPinItem, verb
    'Set the location to pin the item to do based on the passed OnStartMenu argument
    If(trim(lcase(OnStartMenu)) = "true") then
        verbToDo = "Pin to Start Men&u"
    Else    
        verbToDo = "Pin to Tas&kbar"
    End If
    For Each ShortCutToPinItem in ShortCutToPin.Items()
        'Look for the pinning verb when the temporary short-cut name matches the passed ShortcutName argument
        If (ShortCutToPinItem.Name = ShortcutName) Then
            'Loop through the shell object's (the short-cut) commands looking for the pinning method.
            For Each verb in ShortCutToPinItem.Verbs 
                'The verb matches the verbToDo so pin it to verb's defined location
                If (verb.Name = verbToDo) Then verb.DoIt
            Next
        End If
    Next
    'Delete the temporary short-cut used to pin the application
    FileSystemObj.DeleteFile(TempShortcut) 
End If
'clean up
Set ObjShell =  Nothing
Set FileSystemObj = Nothing
Set ObjShellApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

For reference and credit, the code came from here. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/713824/Pin-a-shortcut-onto-the-Taskbar-or-Start-Menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This string concatenation is messed up. It should look like this:

```
WScript.Echo "Missing parameters. String AppPathAndName " & _
             "String ShortcutName Boolean OnStartMenu." & vbCr & vbCr & _
             "Example cmd.exe CMD false" & vbCr & vbCr & _
             "Example %windir%\system32\SnippingTool.exe SnipIt false"
```

You must use both the line continuation (`_`) and the string concatenation (`&`) operators to concat strings across multiple lines in VBScript. Make sure all string literals are closed (every quote has a matching closing quote on the same line).

Comment: Thank you! Got past that part. Now I'm getting an error at (6, 65)

Comment: There was a quote missing there as well. I've updated the code above. Try it again.

Comment: Ok figured that one out before I actually even came back here. This script has quite a few issues apparently. Now I'm getting "Expected Statement at (22, 2) which is this line.

 (ObjShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%TEMP%"))

Comment: The person who wrote this script didn't know how to use line continuation. Tell you what... wherever you see an underscore (`_`), just remove it and combine that line with the one below it. :)

Comment: That's what I assumed when I was looking up what the Unterminated String Constant was. Thank you for the help. Sadly now the script doesn't even work for Windows 8 Start menu :(.